# Need group by and counting query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Suppose I have a table with `threadid` and `itemid` in it. There can be multiple entries of the `itemid` with the same `threadid` value...

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       THREADID, 
       ITEMID 
  FROM THREADS 
 WHERE THREADID IN (SELECT DISTINCT THREADID FROM THREADS WHERE ITEMID = 10151)
```

yields:

```
THREADID    ITEMID
----------- --------------------
149         10000
149         10076
149         10123
149         10151
149         10225
149         10227
149         10243
149         10245
149         10282
149         10310
149         10311
149         10312
149         10350
2000        10151
2000        10243
```

How can I wrap that in another query with group and order by query to get:

```
THREADID      ITEMID
------------- ----------
149         13
2000         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SQL Server 2005+ using CTE:

---

```
  WITH threads_cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT x.threadid 
      FROM THREADS x
     WHERE x.itemid = ?)
  SELECT t.threadid,
         COUNT(DISTINCT t.itemid) 'num_itemid'
    FROM THREADS t
    JOIN threads_cte tc ON tc.threadid = t.threadid
GROUP BY t.threadid
```

### Non CTE Equivalent:

---

```
  SELECT t.threadid,
         COUNT(DISTINCT t.itemid) 'num_itemid'
    FROM THREADS t
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT x.threadid 
            FROM THREADS x
           WHERE x.itemid = ?) y ON y.threadid = t.threadid
GROUP BY t.threadid
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
SELECT  sub.THREADID,
        COUNT(1) TOTAL
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT 
                    t.THREADID, 
                    t.ITEMID 
            FROM    THREADS t INNER JOIN
                    THREADS tt  ON  t.THREADID = tt.THREADID
                                AND tt.ITEMID = 10151
        ) sub
GROUP BY sub.THREADID
ORDER BY sub.THREADID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with FirstQuery AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT THREADID, ITEMID FROM THREADS WHERE THREADID IN (SELECT DISTINCT THREADID FROM THREADS WHERE ITEMID = 10151)
)
SELECT THREADID, COUNT(*)
FROM FirstQuery;
```

Comment: (but make sure that a previous query ended in a semi-colon. Some people like to write `;with`, but it's better to have _ended_ your statement with semi-colons instead of starting them that way.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT THREADID, COUNT(ITEMID) AS ITEMS 
FROM THREADS 
WHERE THREADID IN (SELECT DISTINCT THREADID FROM THREADS WHERE ITEMID = 1059)
GROUP BY THREADID
ORDER BY THREADID
```

Comment: this doesn't take into account that I only want to count an item once if there is more than one record for it.